# .htaccess rewrite URL to other URL no paramters?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a file called `test.php` on `www.example.com/test.php`. Now I would like that if you VISIT `www.example.com/directory/test.php` you get shown the content of `test.php`.

So I don't want to make a 301 redirect. But I do want to people to visit `www.example.com/directory/test.php`. Is the only way to do this to create a new folder in my FTP called `directory` and upload it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a new directory named 'directory', you can do

`RewriteRule ^directory/test\.php$ http://example.com/test.php [P]`

instead.

Comment: But if I do it like that the URL changes and you get redirected to `example.com/test.php`

Comment: [P] is a proxy rewrite and no redirect. For detailed informations you should have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Aha! Thanks, the [P] did it :)